# How to test views that use post request in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, http-post, django-testing

here's my view (simplified):

```
@login_required(login_url='/try_again')
def change_bar(request):
    foo_id = request.POST['fid']
    bar_id = request.POST['bid']
    foo = models.Foo.objects.get(id=foo_id)
    if foo.value > 42:
            bar = models.Bar.objects.get(id=bar_id)
            bar.value = foo.value
            bar.save()
    return other_view(request)
```

Now I'd like to check if this view works properly (in this simplified model, if Bar instance changes value when it should). How do I go about it?

Comment: you can try putting "print" statements in between the code and see if the correct value is saved. Also for update instead of querying with "get" and then saving it (bar.save) you can use "filter" and "update" method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean automated testing rather than just checking that the post request seems to work. If you do mean the latter, just check by executing the request and checking the values of the relevant `Foo` and `Bar` in a shell or in the admin.

The best way to go about sending `POST` requests is using a `Client`. Assuming the name of the view is `my_view`:

```
from django.test import Client
from django.urls import reverse

c = Client()
c.post(reverse('my_view'), data={'fid':43, 'bid':20})
```

But you still need some initial data in the database, and you need to check if the changes you expected to be made got made. This is where you could use a `TestCase`:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse

FooBarTestCase(TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    # create some foo and bar data, using foo.objects.create etc
    # this will be run in between each test - the database is rolled back in between tests

def test_bar_not_changed(self):
    # write a post request which you expect not to change the value 
    # of a bar instance, then check that the values didn't change
    self.assertEqual(bar.value, old_bar.value)

def test_bar_changes(self):
    # write a post request which you expect to change the value of 
    # a bar instance, then assert that it changed as expected
    self.assertEqual(foo.value, bar.value)
```

A library which I find useful for making setting up some data to execute the tests easier is [FactoryBoy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It reduces the boilerplate when it comes to creating new instances of `Foo` or `Bar` for testing purposes. Another option is to write fixtures, but I find that less flexible if your models change.

I'd also recommend [this book](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/) if you want to know more about testing in python. It's django-oriented, but the principles apply to other frameworks and contexts.

edit: added advice about factoryboy and link to book

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I managed to get this tests to work!

I had to add `from django.contrib.auth.models import User ### self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='abc', password='abc') ### c.login(username='abc', password='abc')` to satisfy `@login_required`. Also found out that `self.assertEqual(self.bar.value, good_value)` doesn't work for some reason (that's the `bar` I created in `setUp(self)`). Had to go with `self.assertEqual(Bar.objects.get(id=self.bid).value, good_value)` instead (which gets the same (?) bar).

Comment: Ah good, glad it worked out! `self.assertEqual(Bar.objects.get(id=self.bid).value, good_value)` re-retrieves your `Bar` object from the database, meaning that it's the 'same' `Bar` (in that it has the same primary key) but it's updated with the changes which you made by firing off your `POST` request. You could achieve the same thing by calling `self.bar.refresh_from_db()`, which updates your python object `self.bar` with up to date information from the database.

Answer (score 0):

you can try putting "print" statements in between the code and see if the correct value is saved. Also for update instead of querying with "get" and then saving it (bar.save()) you can use "filter" and "update" method.

```
@login_required(login_url='/try_again')
def change_bar(request):
foo_id = request.POST['fid']
bar_id = request.POST['bid']
foo = models.Foo.objects.get(id=foo_id)
if foo.value > 42:
        models.Bar.objects.filter(id=bar_id).update(value=foo.value)
        #bar.value = foo.value
        #bar.save()
return other_view(request)
```

Comment: Thanks for the .update() method. As for testing, I was thinking about UnitTests, not just "checking by hand".